# Running an angular module from one app into another app. Is that possible?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I have two web apps developed in angular 2. They share few common sets of functionality i.e. of Reward Gallery. That has been developed in one web app. I want the same functionality to be implemented in another app.

So, is there a way to reuse that module in another app by linking or some other way.

Although, there are a few methods to achieve this, for e.g.

- Copy pasting module and making the desired changes in routes and main modules
- Loading the another app in an iframe

But I need a better solution.

Although it seems a bit difficult, but as there's a saying that nothing is impossible. I hope someone has a solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create and publish re-usable Angular modules. Look into ng-packgr for how to do this.

Comment: ok thanks @pixelbits